# Android : Firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I add a full info about a person like name,age,sex etc.
with the date so that I can retrieve data using given date

e.g a data of a month or a day?

shall I use an object to save data if so then how?

And how can I retrieve object data?
This is my class of person

```
class person{
    String fname;
    String lname;
    String sex;
    String address;
    String id;
    int age;
    person(){}
}
```

Shall I  need to add getter/setter?
And shall I make this as an inner class or a normal class?

Comment: You are asking so much questions, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing Java objects to the database, Firebase writes:

- public fields
- properties - defined by a publi getter and/or setter

So at its simplest, this will work:

```
public class person{
    public String fname;
    public String lname;
    public String sex;
    public String address;
    public String id;
    public int age;
}
```

If you define this class inside another class, you will need to make it static:

```
public static class person{
    ...
```